# TextBox event inside DataTemplate doesn't fire

Tags: silverlight

I have attached GotFocus="OnSoldTextBoxGotFocus" event to TextBox inside DataTemplate but it doesn't fire. I want to know how can I make it fire?

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DealerSalePartSaleQty,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource QtyConverter}}"
                    TextAlignment="Right" />
    </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Filters:TextBoxFilterService.Filter="Decimal" MaxLength="8"
                    GotFocus="OnSoldTextBoxGotFocus">
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <!--{Binding WarehouseInventoryData}-->
                <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by your filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for a while. As Rikkos point out in the comment. I forgot to call base.OnGotFocus inside filter.